# Message - Update Functions Version on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, .net-standard-2.0

I have upgraded some of my Azure Functions to .netstandard 2.0, that is still in beta. Whenever I publish my Functions directly from Visual Studio, I get the following message:

[image]

The `csproj` file containing my Functions is already is targeting .netstandard 2.0.

[image]

[image]

Here is the setting in the Function App:

[image]

How can I "upgrade" the version of my local Functions?

Comment: The local function has an updated version (2 or beta) and the setting in Azure is (~1). So this pop up comes, so as to update the setting. Select a yes to automatically do it or manually do it in application settings from portal.

Comment: In the Function App, the setting was already set to beta.

Comment: Just a hunch, but does adding "<AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>" to your .csproj file help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have done some tests on my side and reproduce the message you got. Just like @Connor has said, for function in beta version, the csproj file should include `AzureFunctionsVersion` as the illustration shows.

[image]

Once the `AzureFunctionsVersion` parameter is lost, the function will be recognized as using runtime ~1  despite the `TargetFramework`. So when the project is published to a beta function app in portal, it will remind us of the version change.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! this fix saved my day today!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today during the creation of an Azure Function project in Visual Studio 2019. It needed a lot of sorting out but below turned out to be the solution for me:

In Azure:

1. Azure > Function App > Create
2. Then go to the settings and choose the runtime version, which is ~2 by default (meaning a 2.x version with auto updates enabled).

In Visual Studio:

1. VS Create project type C# > Cloud > 'Azure Functions'. In the second screen don't forget to choose for "Azure Functions v2 (.NET Core)".
2. Via the nuget package manager update the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions package.
3. Also install: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs   (v3.0.9)
4. Also install: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http   (3.0.2)

Clean + Rebuild the project. Now you should be able to Publish directly from Visual Studio to the Cloud. Right-click on the project and choose 'Publish'. Then you should see an option to Publish to an Function in Azure cloud.

If not then the most likely reason is because you have a problem with your references / nuget packages / Microsoft SDK. Or the versions of those.